# Google searches in Internet Explorer redirects to cse.google.com

Tags: windows-10, dns, internet-explorer, malware-removal, malware-detection

In Internet Explorer under Windows 10 Pro, Google searches suddenly redirects to `cse.google.com`. This wasn't happening previously, and this problem does not occur with Firefox. Google searches with Firefox returns results from `www.google.com`.  I have scanned the computer with Malwarebytes, and it did not find any infections. A Windows Defender scan also came up empty.

I have also

- Checked IE's proxy settings
- Checked the computer's network settings for a manual DNS entry
- Checked Group Policy
- Checked the `host` file
- Searched the registry for `cse.google.com`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: I scanned again with Malwarebytes and it found malware. Removing it fixed it. Strange that the scan didn't pick it up the first time.

Comment: You probably encountered some malware that was relatively new, and when you originally scanned with Malwarebytes their definition files weren't updated to detect it yet.  Glad to hear that it ultimately worked out for you.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/iegallery
visit the above. click on the add link below the google logo. I manage to add google search to IE 11 this way

Answer (score 0):

This is merely the [Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/) capability, and it should be harmless.

Personally, I only use IE 11 as a secondary web browser to verify connectivity, web page rendering, etc.  Just something to consider.

Comment: But I didn't make a change. IE was returning results from `www.google.com` when it suddenly switched.

Comment: Understood, but that is a legitimate sub-domain at Google.com, so unless there is something else extraordinary happening to your machine you shouldn't have anything to worry about.  I don't pretend to have in-depth knowledge regarding Google's search engine and advertisement configurations, but after clean scans with both Malwarebytes and Windows Defender, that is a relatively safe computer health assessment.  You could conceivably run another prominent stand-alone scanner like [RKill](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/) if you want some additional peace-of-mind.